# Vuetify: How to horizontally- and vertically align a text field in a parallax

Tags: vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I am trying to horizontally- and vertically align a text field within a parallax in Vuetify. Doing it with text works fine as seen here ([Center text in Parallax](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)) but doing it with a text field fails ([Center Textfield in Parallax](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)).

Code:

```
<template>
<v-app>
    <v-main>
        <v-parallax src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/backgrounds/vbanner.jpg">
            <div class="d-flex flex-column fill-height justify-center align-center text-white">
                <v-text-field label="Your email" clearable variant="solo" prepend-inner-icon="mdi-email-outline" min-width="350">
                    <template v-slot:append-inner>
                        <v-btn class="mt-n1" color="green">
                            Sign up
                        </v-btn>
                    </template>
                </v-text-field>
            </div>
        </v-parallax>
    </v-main>
</v-app>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because the text field has some flex rules on it already.

Add the flex helper class `flex-grow-0` to the text field.

And add `align-self-stretch` to ensure the text field width changes.

To add some spacing either side, add `mx-5` helper class.

```
<v-text-field class="flex-grow-0 align-self-stretch mx5" label="Your email" clearable variant="solo" prepend-inner-icon="mdi-email-outline" min-width="350">
```

Example: [Link](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

Comment: Thanks Alex. Unfortunately, I can't seem to increase the width of the text field though.